# Comparing Data from Column A and Column B Once

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently in the process of analysing data from Excel, and would like to make comparisons between data in Column A and Column B, identifying duplicate data. I am using the following code:

```
Sub Find_Matches()
Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
Set CompareRange = Range("c2", Range("c2").End(xlUp))

For Each x In Selection
    For Each y In CompareRange
        If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x
    Next y
Next x
End Sub
```

This code has been taken from MSDN, so if it finds a match in Column C against Column A, it will display the matched number in Column B. For the most part it does what I need. However I am looking to modify this code so it only matches a number in the list once.

Example of what the code currently does:

```
A2  B2  C2
1   1   1
1   1   2
1   1   3
```

So essentially, because the number 1 appears once in Column C, Column A keeps finding a match.

What I would like it to do is:

```
A2  B2  C2
1   1   1
1       2
1       3
```

So because the number 1 only appears in Column C once, it should only be matched once against the numbers in Column A.

I'm assuming this is probably something simple, but I can't seem to determine the logic. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: I can see why this question has received a downvote. When you say something like "I can't seem to determine the logic", you really ought to follow it with "and this is what I've tried..." And yes, you have posted some code, but it does look like little more than a cut and paste from MSDN. Nonetheless, you probably feel you've tried to meet the spirit of the question etiquette, so I have posted an answer for you.

Comment: @Ambie, Many thanks for your response and my apologies if the question was outside of the usual etiquette. I'm completely new to VBA, hence why the code I was using was taken from the MSDN website and unfortunately I wasn't sure where to start; rest assured I did trawl through the Stackoverflow threads in search of a resolution.

Moving on, thanks for the code below. I have tried to implement it, in it's current form, but receive a type mismatch error. I tried to rectify the fault be debugging, but then receive an expected Array error. I'm still tinkering but thanks again!

Comment: tell me what line the error occurs on and paste the exact error message. I tested the code in my answer and it worked fine, so there's probably an issue with the worksheets. This should be an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

Testing for duplicates can be simple or complicated depending on how fast you want your procedure to be and how large the data sets are.

I personally favour the `Collection` object because it has a unique key and testing for the existence of that key is very fast, especially if the dataset is large. The unique test is done by seeing if the code throws an error when you interrogate the `Collection` for a particular key. Some are philosophically opposed to testing for errors - I have to say that I'm one, so I actually prefer the `Dictionary` object but for a task this mundane, I won't go through the steps to reference that.

You'll also see that the code below works with arrays rather than cells on the worksheet itself - again, just a matter of personal taste because it's quicker.

```
Const SOURCE_COL As String = "A"
Const SOURCE_START_ROW As Long = 2
Const COMPARE_COL As String = "C"
Const COMPARE_START_ROW As Long = 2
Const OUTPUT_COL As String = "B"

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sourceValues As Variant
Dim compareValues As Variant
Dim outputValues() As Variant
Dim sourceIndex As Long
Dim compareIndex As Long
Dim uniques As Collection
Dim val As Variant
Dim key As String
Dim exists As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
sourceValues = ws.Range(ws.Cells(SOURCE_START_ROW, SOURCE_COL), _
                        ws.Cells(Rows.Count, SOURCE_COL).End(xlUp)).Value2

compareValues = ws.Range(ws.Cells(COMPARE_START_ROW, COMPARE_COL), _
                         ws.Cells(Rows.Count, COMPARE_COL).End(xlUp)).Value2

Set uniques = New Collection
ReDim outputValues(1 To UBound(sourceValues, 1), 1 To 1)

For sourceIndex = 1 To UBound(sourceValues, 1)

    val = sourceValues(sourceIndex, 1)
    key = CStr(val)
    exists = Empty
    On Error Resume Next
    exists = uniques(key)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If IsEmpty(exists) Then

        For compareIndex = 1 To UBound(compareValues, 1)
            If val = compareValues(compareIndex, 1) Then
                outputValues(sourceIndex, 1) = val
                uniques.Add val, key
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

    End If

Next

ws.Cells(SOURCE_START_ROW, OUTPUT_COL).Resize(UBound(outputValues, 1)).Value = outputValues
```

Comment: Hi Ambie, 
as per the comment above, the error message I am receiving is:

Run-Time Error '13':
Type Mismatch 

Error on Ln 27 "ReDim outputValues(1 To UBound(sourceValues, 1), 1 To 1))"

At this point I changed the sourceValues to an Integer value (not sure why? I was just playing around), and then receive the "Expected Array" error. I'm googling between MSDN and SO, trying different suggestions, but to no avail.

Once again, many thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, so that's a problem with the `sourceValues` variable. Most likely the variant is empty. Check the constants `SOURCE_COL` and `SOURCE_START_ROW` are correct - I've set them to cell A2. Then check that the worksheet actually has some values in the `SOURCE_COL` column. Finally, change to two `sourceValues` and `compareValues` lines from `...Rows.Count...` to `...ws.Rows.Count...`

Comment: I modified the `SOURCE_COL` and`SOURCE_START_ROW` to A1, same for the other two constants (C1), as well as adding the `ws.` prior to `Rows.Count` in both instances. Issue still remains unfortunately. Unsure what's going wrong as data is present in the sheet and is in the correct format? Also, is this only comparing against the value 1? Is it not possible to analyse all the numbers in the WS to compare against using the `collection ` object?

Comment: @J.Doe, I think you're going to have to read up on how to set ranges. Only you can know the structure of your worksheet and I'm certain this is the issue. If you use the code `sourceValues = ws.UsedRange.Columns(SOURCE_COL).Value2` and `compareValues = ws.UsedRange.Columns(COMPARE_COL).Value2` then you should acquire some values but it will include every cell in each of the columns (even if there are headers). Also read up on how to step through your code (use F8) to see the contents of your variables as you need to see what's in `sourceValues` and `compareValues`.